# How to integrate Google SingIn react native and Spring Boot Security OAuth2?

Tags: spring-boot, react-native, jwt, spring-security-oauth2, expo-auth-session

I have a mobile app in react native that uses expo-auth-session to be able to log in with its google account.

I have spring boot application that has oauth2 configuration as you can see below:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            clientId: clientIdValue
            clientSecret: clientSecretValue
            redirectUri: "https://localhost/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}"
            scope:
              - email
              - profile
```

How can i integrate this react-native app to works with spring boot application in signin/signup?

I need to be able to authenticate the user on my backend to get a jwt token so I can access the rest of my endpoints.

The problem I find is that if I use the oauth2 library of my spring boot using these urls:
`https://localhost/oauth2/authorize/google? redirect_uri=https://localhost/oauth2/redirect.`
i can't redirect to my mobile app and if I use expo-auth-session to login the user from my mobile app, i don't have the necessary information to authenticate with oauth2 in my backend.

What is the best way to do this?
Is there a way to redirect back to my mobile app after authentication in my backend? I know that I can know if the call was from mobile using userAgentInfo

Answer (score 0):

Your Spring app is most probably a REST API, and as so, a **resource-server**, not a **client**, which means your Spring conf is most probably wrong. Tutorials for configuring resource-servers on [this repo of mine](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons)

Regarding your React-Native app, you could consider make it an OAuth2 **client** with the help of [`react-native-app-auth`](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth). I have no direct experience with React Native, but with Cordova apps, it required me to setup "deep links" for redirection back from authorization server.